# Nginx does redirect, not proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy for a https service, because we have a special usecase where we need to "un-https" a connection:

`http://nginx_server:8080/myserver ==> https://mysecureservice`

But what happens is that the actual https service isn't proxied. Nginx does redirect me to the actual service, so the URL in the browser changes. I want to interact with Nginx as it was the actual service, just without https.

This is what I have:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080 default_server;
    location /myserver {
        proxy_pass https://myserver/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the `proxy_redirect` to handle the redirection.

```
 Sets the text that should be changed in the “Location” and “Refresh” header fields of a 
 proxied server response. Suppose a proxied server returned the header field 
 “Location:https://myserver/uri/”. The directive
 will rewrite this string to “Location: http://nginx_server:8080/uri/”.
```

Example:

```
 proxy_redirect https://myserver/ http://nginx_server:8080/;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. It does not work even for non-redirection URLs. I always get redirected, not matter if the actual https server does send a Location header or not: 

```proxy_redirect   https://mysecureservice/  http://$host:$server_port/myserver/;```

Comment: Where does the redirection come from? If it's from the https server html, you have to `subs_filter` it. If there is a cookie, you may have to rewrite it.

Comment: The redirection definitely comes from Nginx. I'm not using HTML, I'm using JSON. If I do ```curl https://mysecureserver/api/v3/user -I``` (call the actual server directly), I get a 200 OK. If I do the same with Nginx: ```curl http://nginx_server:8080/myserver/api/v3/user -I```, I get a 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: Is the HTTP host in `proxy_set_header Host $host;` correct? It has to be mysecureserver.

Comment: With all the upvotes I must simply not understand what's wanted. I understood that mitchkman wants to proxy NOT redirect because a redirect is what's already happening. This answer says how to redirect, which is the opposite of what's asked for.

Comment: @Altimus Prime: I am with you. Spend one of my rep points to downvote. Just asking me, why this is accepted as a correct answer too.

Comment: @Altimus Prime, and others who don't understand, because you misunderstood the `proxy_redirect`. Don't be confused with its name. Although it has "redirect" literally in its name, it has nothing to do with "redirect". Go read the doc. All it does is to modify the "Location" or "Refresh" field in the response header. The request is `proxy_pass`'ed by the nginx to `myserver`, and the response comes back from `myserver` to the nginx proxy, and with `proxy_redirect`, some of the fields in the response header are modified before sent back to the client. Isn't it a proxy?

Comment: @Bruce We understand what `proxy_redirect` does. The OP specically asked "Nginx does redirect, not proxy" indicating that they wanted to proxy, but this answer redirects. Again, that isn't what was asked for and this answer is served by Google to people looking to reverse proxy, which is really annoying and unhelpful.

Comment: @AltimusPrime, Doesn't sound like you understand. The OP wanted to proxy, this answer does proxy.

Comment: @AltimusPrime after I try, it does proxy. But sometimes the **source page** return 301 with `Location` header which then passed to **proxy server** and served to client browser. `proxy_redirect` rewrites this header so the browser redirects to **proxy server** address instead of the source page directly. I was looking for the way nginx follow redirects internally and serve the final page to browser but stumbled upon here, which is not the answer I'm looking for

Comment: First I downvoted because it doesn't answer why is nginx redirecting instead of proxying, but, the truth is that this answer solved my problem. I will undo my downvote and upvote.

Answer (score 14):

You can setup nginx like this if you do not want the server to do redirects:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name YOUR.OWN.DOMAIN.URL;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://THE.SITE.URL.YOU.WANT.TO.DELEGAGE/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this config was sufficient:

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that the `resolver` directive has nothing to do with the problem in the OP, I just needed it to be able to proxy an external domain such as `example.com`)

The problem for me was just that I was missing the `www.` in `www.example.com`. In the Firefox developer's console, I could see the GET request to `localhost` coming back with a 301, and so I thought that NGINX was issuing 301s instead of just mirroring `example.com`. Not so: in fact the problem was that `example.com` was returning 301s to redirect to `www.example.com`, NGINX was dutifully mirroring those 301s, and then Firefox "changed the URL" (followed the redirect) straight from `localhost` to `www.example.com`.

Comment: Forgot www here too, it's just really easy to forget.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue as well.

Comment: God bless you, this saved me !

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by added a trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` URL:

#### before

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/path/to/some/folder;
  }
}
```

#### after

```
server {
  location / {
    # added trailing slash
    proxy_pass http://example.com/path/to/some/folder/;
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have two location like this.
`
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://next:3000/;
        }

        location /legacy/ {
            proxy_pass http://frontend/legacy;
        }
`
I get redirect _internal redirect 304_ to `www.example.com` whenever I enter `www.example.com/legacy`.
Now the problem gone by adding trailing slash as you said.