# How to correctly redirect a request with $scheme via proxy_pass using nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have setup two nginx instances as follows:

```
nginx (https) → docker:[nginx (http) → uwsgi]
```

The front facing nginx process exposes the `https` service, which passes down all requests via `proxy_pass` to the *docker* nginx process. It also redirects all requests to `http` → `https`.

The problem is that the docker nginx process has the following line in a location block in its default server instance:

```
server {
    ...
    location = / {
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host${request_uri}login/;
    }
}
```

With the intention of redirecting / to the login page. This works fine except that the redirection always points to an `http://...` url. E.g. A request to `http://myserver.com/`, gets redirected to `https://myserver.com/`, then it gets passed down to the docker nginx which returns a 301 with the following url: `http://myserver.com/login/`. I want it to be `https://myserver.com/login/` or whatever schema the front-facing server may offer.

This is how I setup the front-facing nginx process:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;

        proxy_redirect     https:// http://;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    ...

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$http_host${request_uri};
    }

}
```

Is this kind of redirection even possible?

Also, in case you wonder, I also tried all possible combinations of `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Scheme` and `proxy_redirect` as other answers suggest, namely:

[Nginx does redirect, not proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520540/nginx-does-redirect-not-proxy)

[how to handle nginx reverse proxy https to http scheme redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656273/how-to-handle-nginx-reverse-proxy-https-to-http-scheme-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

One trick that I've found is that you can disable absolute redirects (e.g. instead of redirecting to http://localhost/your_url_with_trailing_slash_now it will redirect to /your_url_with_trailing_slash_now).

add the following to any point within the server block (of the nginx instance that does this 301 redirect, in your case the nginx-docker instance):

```
server {
  absolute_redirect off;
  ...
```

More info can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/227742/prevent-port-change-on-redirect-in-nginx